# Merge sort on linked lists

Tags: c++, linked-list, mergesort, divide-and-conquer

I was trying a merge sort on linked lists.

I was keeping my head variable global and applied the basic algorithm i.e. divide and conquer.

I am not understanding why I am getting a segmentation fault.

I know I could do it by passing head as a reference, but i still need to know why this is happening.

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

class Node {
  public:
    int data;
    Node *next;
};
Node *head;

void push(Node **head_ref, int x) {
    Node *temp = new Node();
    temp->next = *head_ref;
    temp->data = x;
    *head_ref = temp;
}

void split(Node *temp, Node **a, Node **b) {
    Node *slow;
    Node *fast;
    slow = temp;
    fast = temp->next;
    while (fast != NULL) {
        fast = fast->next;
        if (fast != NULL) {
            slow = slow->next;
            fast = fast->next;
        }
    }
    *a = temp;
    *b = slow->next;
    slow->next = NULL;
}

Node *mergesort(Node *a, Node *b) {
    if (a == NULL) {
        return b;
    } else
    if (b == NULL) {
        return a;
    }
    if (a->data < b->data) {
        a->next = mergesort(a->next, b);
        return a;
    } else {
        b->next = mergesort(a, b->next);
        return b;
    }
}  

void merge(Node **head_ref) {
     Node *head = *(head_ref);
     Node *a;
     Node *b;
     if (head == NULL || head->next == NULL) {
         return;
     }
     split(head, &a, &b);
     merge(&a);
     merge(&b);
     head = mergesort(a, b);
}

void print(Node *n) {
    while (n != NULL) {
        cout << n->data << " ";
        n = n->next;
    }
}
```

My Main method is below:

```
int main() {
    Node *head;
    push(&head, 1);
    push(&head, 3);
    push(&head, 6);
    push(&head, 4);
    push(&head, 2);
    print(head);
    merge(&head);
    cout << endl;
    print(head);
}
```

Comment: You can accept the answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few simple bugs in your code:

- `head` is defined as a global variable, but also as a local variable in `main`, so this local variable is used inside `main` and not the global one. There is indeed no need for a global variable.
- The local variable `Node *head;` in `main()` is not initialized. All the `push` calls will succeed, constructing a list pointed to by `head` but with an undefined pointer for the `next` node after `1`, `print` will crash trying to dereference this pointer. The behavior is undefined, you might habe a null pointer by chance in `head` but you might might instead have an invalid pointer, causing undefined behavior. Initialize `head` to `NULL`:

  ```
      Node *head = NULL;
  ```
- at the end of `merge`, you do not update the head pointer through `head_ref`, so the variable in the callers is not updated. Write this:

  ```
      *head_ref = mergesort(a, b);
  ```

Note that it would be simpler for `merge` to receive a `Node *head` pointer and return the updated `Node *` head pointer.

Note also that your function names are confusing: `merge` should be named `mergesort` and vice-versa.

Here is a modified version:

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

class Node {
  public:
    int data;
    Node *next;
};

void push(Node **head_ref, int x) {
    Node *temp = new Node();
    if (temp) {
        temp->next = *head_ref;
        temp->data = x;
        *head_ref = temp;
    }
}

void split(Node *temp, Node **a, Node **b) {
    Node *slow = temp;
    Node *fast = temp->next;
    while (fast != NULL) {
        fast = fast->next;
        if (fast != NULL) {
            slow = slow->next;
            fast = fast->next;
        }
    }
    *a = temp;
    *b = slow->next;
    slow->next = NULL;
}

Node *merge(Node *a, Node *b) {
    if (a == NULL) {
        return b;
    }
    if (b == NULL) {
        return a;
    }
    if (a->data <= b->data) {
        a->next = merge(a->next, b);
        return a;
    } else {
        b->next = merge(a, b->next);
        return b;
    }
}  

Node *mergesort(Node *head) {
     Node *a;
     Node *b;
     if (head == NULL || head->next == NULL) {
         return head;
     }
     split(head, &a, &b);
     a = mergesort(a);
     b = mergesort(b);
     return merge(a, b);
}

void print(const Node *n) {
    while (n != NULL) {
        cout << n->data << " ";
        n = n->next;
    }
    count << endl;
}

int main() {
    Node *head = NULL;
    push(&head, 1);
    push(&head, 3);
    push(&head, 6);
    push(&head, 4);
    push(&head, 2);
    print(head);
    head = mergesort(head);
    print(head);
    return 0;
}
```